# repeat the the following code n times in R

Tags: r, statistics

Hi everyone i want to repeat the code n times and the result of x saved into a vector in R program. Can you help write this in R?

```
x<-c()
i<-1
y<-c()
repeat {
    
    x[i]<-runif(1)
    i=i+1
    if(sum(x)>1) {
      break
    }
  }

x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with `replicate`. First convert your code into a function:

```
myfunction <- function() {
  x <- c()
  i <- 1
  repeat {
    x[i] <- runif(1)
    i <- i + 1
    if(sum(x) > 1) {
         return(x)
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Notice we must explicitly return `x` from the function. Now use replicate to run the function multiple times:

```
set.seed(42)   # Use for repeatability of the example
results <- replicate(10, myfunction())
```

Now `results` is a list with each run as a separate element:

```
results[[1]]
# [1] 0.9148060 0.9370754
sapply(results, length)   # How many elements in each run
# [1] 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2
sapply(results, sum)      # What was the sum of each run
#  [1] 1.851881 1.116587 1.160841 1.528247 1.162807 1.653784 1.657736 1.095714 1.035330 1.042742
```

Comment: Thank you, its a great answer